# R legend - How can I change position

Tags: windows

I want to put the legend in a corner. But, I don't know the steps to doind this.

I've tried:"topleft", legend=....)

But the plot didn't changed:

Comment: can you please provide some more information on what you want?

Comment: This post appears to be [off-topic](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) as per *Questions that lack sufficient information to diagnose the problem.* Please edit your post accordingly to add sufficient detail so that people may help you.